# Come someone explain why this code won't work for me?

Tags: python

I have this program I am writing and it's supposed to only use one for. The for is needed to ask what the names and scores are. Also, the for is needed to write the scores and names to the file. I get an error when trying to run it saying "UnsupportedOperation: Not Readable"

```
Golf_File = open('golf.txt', 'w')

names = []
scores = []

for line in Golf_File:
    input("Please enter a players name: ")
    if name !='':
        break
    score = input("Please input the players score: ")
    if name != '' and score !="":
        golf.txt.write(name + "\n")(str(score) + "\n")
        Golf_File.close()





EDIT =
for line in Golf_File:
    Golf_File = open('golf.txt', 'w')
    names = input("Please enter a players name: ")
    score = input("Please input the players score: ")
    Golf_File.write(str(names) + "\n")
    Golf_File.write(str(scores) + "\n")

    Golf_File.close()
```

Comment: You cannot read from a file (`for line in Golf_File:`) if the file is currently opened in write (`'w'`) mode (`open('golf.txt', 'w')`).

Comment: @Brokke2 from where you get `name`?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi I forgot to add the s back into that.

Comment: I cannot follow the logic in your program. Are you trying to *update* `golf.txt` with newly entered data? That `close` inside your read loop isn't helping things either...

Comment: I am trying to create a new document called golf.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your answer you opened Golf_File with "w" which means write while you want to read the file. To read a file use "r" instead of "w" aka

```
Golf_File = open('golf.txt', 'r')

for line in Golf_File:
    Golf_File = open('golf.txt', 'w')
    names = input("Please enter a players name: ")
    score = input("Please input the players score: ")
    Golf_File.write(str(names) + "\n")
    Golf_File.write(str(score) + "\n")

Golf_File.close()
```

Im not 100% sure this works because i don't know whats inside of golf.txt but hopefully this could help you. If there are any mistakes be welcome to correct me :). I made some edits like changing a variable name that was wrong and changing "r"(read) to "wr"(write and read). also put the file close after the loop so it would work more than one time. I thought wr was a thing but i was wrong prbly

Comment: I get it to allow me to enter the players name, but then won't go to the players score.

Comment: can you please show me golf.txt because i don't understand whats being inputed without it

Comment: I am creating the file to put the names and scores in.

Comment: because name is not defined. instead of "input(Please enter a players name: )" do "name = input("Please enter a players name: ")

Comment: I did an edit of the original post under it for what I have right now.

Comment: I am able to enter a players name and score but forces me to type both in twice.

Comment: and like the person above said you should close the file only after your loop. I will make some changes which should be similair to what you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207381/discussion-between-theicepheonix-and-brokke2).